# Session in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, session, spring-boot

My project is a springboot application with basic crud functionality with a login page using HTML and CSS only. How do I add session for login and logout

Comment: why dont you use spring security for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended to use Spring Security.

You can find a lot of example if you search for "spring security tutorial" in google.

For instance it is an offical tutorial with angular js (1.x)
https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/

If you don't want to use spring security you have to create a http session and store the logged in user data in http session.

In spring you can inject the HttpSession to your bean and you can add session attributes, or you can create a session scoped bean.

Answer (score 3):

As others have suggested, you can use Spring security. Or if you don't want to deal with the complexities of Spring Security, you can get `HttpSession` object in your controller's handlers' methods' arguments. You can set values or objects in that session using `HttpSession.setAttribute("name you want to refer to", actual value or object)` once a user logs in. And when a user presses logout, you can use `HttpSession.invalidate();` to finish the session.

Comment: Hey,
I am making something similar. I have homepage where a link is provided to sign in as a user. User can use the application without sign in as well.
Now, i have created a rest endpoint for sign in and call it using ajax to authenticate email and password from mysql database. I want to mantain the login session of that user untill he logs out himself or certain time has elapsed. I read i could use spring security but not clear how . I am clear on how to use session attribute but i want to use spring security for that matter , can anyone help. ?

Comment: @SahilGupta I have not used Spring security. I don't know how to maintain session when security is at play.

Comment: @FarazDurrani I try to use HttpSession, but It not persist between requests. Can you help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648205/java-spring-session-not-persist-between-requests , please?

Answer (score 2):

The best solution to this would be the use of Spring Security.
Take a look at this: https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/.

Answer (score 1):

easy tutorial of spring web security [see link here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login) and [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example/)

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security is best option for authentication and authorization. For login, if new user got logged in then you need to maintain session for particular user until logout. You can use Spring security session management.

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session

You can set UserDetails object in http.setAttribute("USER_DETAILS", userDetails);

(userDetails is object of UserDetails which is in built class)

You can use this httpSession object like httpSession.getAttribute("USER_DETAILS"); for manipulation further. For logout use can use httpSession.invalidate() method.