# Java Spring Session not persist between requests

Tags: java, spring, session

I have this controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public class Login{

    @RequestMapping
    public ModelAndView mainPage(HttpServletRequest request){

        request.getSession().setAttribute("testSession", "Session test");

        return new ModelAndView("/login");

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/check")
    public View check(HttpServletRequest request){

        System.out.println(request.getSession(false)); //null

        return new RedirectView("/login");

    }

}
```

When access `/login` I create a session and add an attribute `"testSession"` into it: `request.getSession().setAttribute("testSession", "Session test");`

On page `/login` have this `<form action="/login/check" method="post">`.

On `/login/check` I try to get session created on `/login`, but it is null.

Why session not persist between requests?

P.S.: My app run on Remote Server with Tomcat and Apache as revers proxy and I access my app via `https://mydom.com`

**UPDATE**

I created a controller to test session:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/sess")
public class TestSession{

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void mainPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{

        //get or create session
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.getWriter().println(session.getId());

    }

}
```

At every request to `/sess` it's printed another id.

Comment: How are you testing this? Make sure that you are sending the session id from the client back to the server.

Comment: @M.Deinum How exactly? I'm new with spring/web

Comment: That has nothing to do with Spring but all with how you are testing this. If you aren't sending the sessionId cookie (assuming you are using cookies) then there is nothing to restore. Also make sure you have configured Spring Session correctly.

Comment: @M.Deinum can we please talk here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195135/room-for-kunlun-and-m-deinum ? I feel like I'm missing information.

Comment: Just explain (or show) how you are testing this. You are discussing pages, which pages, show how you are doing things. Also add your Spring Session configuration (there should be a filter configured).

Comment: Login page contains a form with action `/login/check`. `/login/check` - check session and redirect back to login page. I have no `Spring Session configuration`.

Comment: @KunLun, you set attribute `testSession` and send it to page `/login`. What is login? Is it a JSP? If yes, then test if you can read that attribute in a JSP. You can find example here https://beginnersbook.com/2013/11/jsp-implicit-object-session-with-examples/. Now, I think the problem is, from `/login` page, you are not sending this attribute to the method that handles `/check` endpoint. So you will probably need to set this attribute again in `/login` JSP. And then you should be able to read it in a method that handles `/check` endpoint.

Comment: @FarazDurrani Yes, `login` is a jsp and I can read `testSession` on `login` page. Of course I don't send `testSession` to `check`. The Idea of session is to store data linked with user which persist until browser is closed and not to send this data between requests.

Comment: Kunlun, you may need to brush up on sessions. If you don't want to manually send data between requests, then consider using Spring Security.

Comment: @kunlun, lookup `@SessionAttribute` and see if that solves the problem without using Spring Security.

Comment: How do you call the `check` method? Since there no `RequestMethod` specified it's using its default one (GET). Are you using a redirect from the client side? This can generate a new session. Moreover, as @M.Deinum said, check if you are passing the session id. How? Check if in the URL you have something like JSESSIONID=XXXXXX or if you have any cookie with the session id. You can check all the network traffic by using developers tools in google chrome

Comment: @AngeloImmediata I call `check` from `login.jsp` with `<form action="/login/check">`. I have a cookie JSESSIONID, but his value changes after every request. Even if I refresh login page

Comment: Try to make a submit instead of a get

Comment: Let's proceed by steps. Are you testing by running your app on your laptop without passing by a web server (e.g. apache, ngnix or other)? if not... may you test the app on your laptop and check if the behavior is the same?

Comment: Normally I test it direct on server. But now I tested `/sess` on local and session persist. So the problem is not at app? It may be from Tomcat/Apache?

Comment: If the session persists, we can assume that the issue is not related to the app. Are you using a single server or a cluster? Is your apache configured in a sticky-session mode? Is there any other firewall or other that can filter requests?

Comment: Single server. The only think I configured to Apache are 2 VirtualHosts. First `<VirtualHost *:80>`(http) which redirect permanent to `https(port 443)`. The other one `<VirtualHost *:443>`(https) where enable `SSLCertificate` and set reverse proxy like this: `ProxyRequests off`, `ProxyPreserveHost on`, `ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/` and `ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/`. I don't know if there is a firewall or filter request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195351/discussion-between-angelo-immediata-and-kunlun).

Comment: @AngeloImmediata I solved. Read my answer. And really thanks for all your helping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The real problem was at JSessionID path.

The path of JSessionID was `/myapp`. That was result of Tomcat, because my app normaly run under `mydom.com:8080/myapp`

But with Apache as reverse proxy, I run my app directly from `mydom.com/`, which make `JSessionID` invalid because I'm not on `mydom.com/myapp`.

So I added a new line in virtual host from Apache(where is setted reverse proxy) to change the path of cookies:

```
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /myapp /
```

This is my final `VirtualHost` and now Session persist between requests.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName mydom.com

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /myapp /

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: If someone thinks there are missing/wrong information from this answer, please leave a comment with details to update the response.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using spring security? May be you can set 
`http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)` if you are managing sessions by yourself

Reference: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session

Comment: I'm not using spring security

Comment: That only influences how Spring Security handles sessions NOT how the remainder of your application is handling it.